# Using controllers added by routes to declare $scope variables in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, scope

My application is an SPA. It includes templates based on route. It also declares a scope variable based on route. I accomplished that last part by setting a controller for each route on the .config service.

This is my config...

```
spa.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            })
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/about.html',
                controller: 'aboutController'
            })
            .when('/skills', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/skills.html',
                controller: 'skillsController'
            })
            .when('/experience', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/experience.html',
                controller: 'experienceController'
            })
            .when('/resume', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/resume.html',
                controller: 'resumeController'
            })
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/contact.html',
                controller: 'contactController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home'
            });
});
```

These are all my controllers...

```
/*Template Controllers*/

var homeController = spa.controller("homeController", function($scope) {
    $scope.currentLink = "home";
})

var aboutController = spa.controller("aboutController", function($scope) {
    $scope.currentLink = "about";
})

var skillsController = spa.controller("skillsController", function($scope) {
    $scope.currentLink = "skills";
})

var experienceController = spa.controller("experienceController", function($scope) {
    $scope.currentLink = "experience";
})

var resumeController = spa.controller("resumeController", function($scope) {
    $scope.currentLink = "resume";
})

var contactController = spa.controller("contactController", function($scope) {
    $scope.currentLink = "contact";
})

/*Dynamic CSS Linking*/

var cssController = spa.controller("cssController", function($scope) {
    this.fileName = $scope.currentLink;
});

/*Navigation Controller*/

var navigationController = spa.controller("navigationController", function($scope) {
    this.checkCurrent = function(checkValue) {
        return $scope.currentLink == checkValue;
    }
    this.linkValues = [
    {linkContent: "Home", linkValue: "home"},
    {linkContent: "About", linkValue: "about"},
    {linkContent: "Skills", linkValue: "skills"},
    {linkContent: "Experience", linkValue: "experience"},
    {linkContent: "Resume", linkValue: "resume"},
    {linkContent: "Contact", linkValue: "contact"}
    ];
});
```

And this is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="spa">
    <head ng-controller="cssController as cssCtrl">
        <title>
            Allen Hundley
        </title>
        <!--Favicon-->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://allenhundley.com/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="http://allenhundley.com/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <!--End Favicon-->
        <!--CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://allenhundley.com/css/base.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ng-href="http://allenhundley.com/css/partials_css/{{ cssCtrl.fileName + '.css' }}">
        <!--End CSS-->
        <!--JavaScript Sources-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://allenhundley.com/resources/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://allenhundley.com/resources/angular-route.js"></script>
        <!--End JavaScript Source-->
        <!--JavaScript-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://allenhundley.com/js/modules.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://allenhundley.com/js/services.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://allenhundley.com/js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://allenhundley.com/js/directives.js"></script>
        <!--End JavaScript-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navigation">
            <div id="link_wrapper" ng-controller="navigationController as navCtrl">
                <navigation-links></navigation-links>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-view id="wrapper"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

All controllers and factories are applied to the `spa` module.

The links in my page link to new routes. That part works perfectly. Additionally the controllers which are added by the route declare a scope variable which is later grabbed by some other controllers.

The first place this scope variable is used is in the `cssController`. The intent of this controller is to dynamically link a css file which will pertain to the HTML template.

The second place this scope variable is used is in the `navigationController`. Although you can't see it, in each link in the element directive there is a link to `navigationController`'s `checkCurrent` function. This function returns a boolean that affects whether the link has CSS applied to it which makes it the "active" link.

The problem here is that either my scope variable isn't getting declared, or I'm not accessing it correctly.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Still not clear what you're trying to convey. May be a plunker could help

Comment: What is a plunker? Anything I can do to make it more clear?

Comment: recreate the problem on this site : http://plnkr.co/edit/

Answer (score 0):

Are you intent to share `currentLink` across all controllers in your app?
If it is, then there are couple ways of doing it.

The first way is using `$rootScope`. The `$scope` you use is not shared among controllers, they are different instance, each bound to a view that the controller is declared on. `$rootScope` is your top level `$scope` which only have one instance per app, and you can conveniently inject it into all controllers.

```
var homeController = spa.controller("homeController", function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.currentLink = "home";
})
```

If you don't have too much data that needs to be shared in global scope (which you shouldn't), you can use this approach. Or even make an object to hold it if you have a couple more.

```
$rootScope.data = {};
```

The second way is to use a service. This is more "formal" way of sharing data between selected controllers. Controllers that needs the data will inject the service, and controllers that don't will not aware of it. There are many guides which teach you how to setup a service, here is just one of the way.

```
spa.service('Navigation', function(){
    this.currentLink= null;

    // some people prefer get and set method here
    // var currentLink;
    // this.getLink = function() {return currentLink;}
    // this.setLink = function(input) {currentLink = input;}

    // and some uses an object wrapper for binding
    // this.data = {currentLink: null};

    // depends on which one suits your need and preference
});
```

In controller you inject them and use it like `$rootScope`

```
var homeController = spa.controller("homeController", function($scope, Navigation) {
    Navigation.currentLink = "home";
})
```

---

**Edit:** In this case where you are trying to match by route name only, you can just use `$location.path()` to determine the current path.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fojijaxoqo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I actually just recently discovered this myself. You're very right on all counts. The problem I'm having here is actually acquiring the current route dynamically.

Comment: You can get the route by `$location.path()`, is that what you need?

Comment: $location.path() will give me the route when I load the page. I have a single page application, so I need it to update whenever the route changes.

Comment: Try it out. Actually the url changes even it's a SPA. SPA has long evolved from using the same URL

Comment: Join me in chat? 

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25345/acquiring-dynamic-route